# how to integrate moengage into ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

can anyone know how to integrate moengage into ionic app?

there is a document mentioned in moengage documents but it was not perfectly working as expected. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: @abhimitra : Not sure if you are still looking for help with this, but you can refer the following sample project : https://github.com/moengage/IonicMoEngageIntegration

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below link for reference:https://github.com/moengage/MoEngage-iOS-SDK

To install manually, follow the steps below:

Download the latest sdk from the following link.

Add the given library file (.a extension) from MoEngageSDK folder to your project.

Add the given header files (.h extensions) from MoEngageSDK folder, by dragging and dropping the files in to your project.

Add the following compiler flag: -ObjC. Select your project. Go to “Build Settings” ->”Linker” ->”Other Linker Flags” and add this flag.

Comment: i want to integrate moengage cordova plugin and after installing plugin what are the next steps i have to follow can you help me. moengage team already prepared a document
refer this link
https://docs.moengage.com/docs/sdk-integration-1
but the steps after plugin installation should not be perfect.